# How to restrain the scroll of the map to the size of the layer (ImageStatic)?

Tags: openlayers-3

I think that all is in the question, i'm looking for a way to fixed the scrollable area of the map to the size of it's layer.

In my case i use a static image which has 2722 px in width and 3850 px in height.

I also check the "extent" property but i can't really anderstand how to make it work, for my purpose.

That's it, can't wait for some clues or other answers :)

Have a nice day & code.

EDIT:

```
var extent = [0, 0, 2722, 3850];
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'xcd-image',
    units: 'pixels',
    extent: extent
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({mouseWheelZoom: false, doubleClickZoom: false}),
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
          url: 'http://www.tarsis.paris/bundles/tarsisfront/carte.png',
          projection: projection,
          imageExtent: extent
        })
      })
    ],
    controls: [],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: projection,
      center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
      zoom: 3
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of the code you're working on in your question?

Comment: i just edited the code for creating the map. I follow the static image example on their site :) Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea how to proceed to solve this issue ? I edited the question as you requested. Can't wait for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would like to achieve is not yet supported by OpenLayers. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/127854/42826) by one of the OL developers.

As indicated by a comment in the question referenced above, you can though restrict zoomlevels by adding the `minZoom` parameter. You would have to change this part of your code:

```
controls: [],
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
  projection: projection,
  center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
  zoom: 3
})
```

to this:

```
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
  projection: projection,
  center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
  zoom: 3,
  minZoom: 2
})
```